# How to deny access to all URLs by default?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

When defining new spring boot REST resources, I tend to forget to also create a spring security configuration for their url patterns.

How can I, by default, deny access to all URLs, and only allow access to explicitly configured URL patterns? (I am using `.hasRole` for to allow access) I want to avoid as many unintended security holes as possible.

Let's say I have three REST resources: `/jobs`, `/desks` and `/salary`. My current code might look like this:

```
http.authorizeRequests()

    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/jobs")
    .hasRole("my_user")

    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/desks")
    .hasRole("my_user");
```

But currently, access to url `/salary` is provided to everyone (because it is not yet configured)!

Comment: `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
    .access("hasRole('ADMIN')"` allows everything but everything following an admin url? Or maybe `http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/admin*/**").authenticated()
.anyRequest().permitAll()
.and()
.csrf().disable();`?

Comment: If they are starting with same pattern for eg : /api/... then you can deny that url patters using spring security. Otherwise that urls always open for users.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can deny all requests by default with: `.anyRequest().denyAll()`
and explicit allow requests with `.hasRole`

Answer (score 18):

Spring's [Expression-Based Access Control](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) has a `denyAll` expression which always evaluates to `false`.

So what you can do is use this `denyAll` method to deny access to everything, and then perhaps allow access to a certain URL(s) via `hasRole`:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')").antMatchers("/**").denyAll();
```

So for example, this will allow users with ADMIN access to access any page starting with `/admin`. And then it will deny access to all other pages. Note that the order is important as if you put in `.antMatchers("/**").denyAll()` *first*, it will deny **all** access and ignore the rest of your expression.

Or alternatively, you could use `permitAll()` for a certain URL pattern:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/**").denyAll();
```

Just to note that you might need to allow access to some way of logging in too, so the system can let someone log in with a specific role, so to combine it all together, and allow everyone to try login, only admin users to access the admin page(s) and deny all others, then something like:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')").antMatchers("/**").denyAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

`anyRequest().denyAll()` to deny all requests by default and
`.hasRole` to explicit allow requests

Comment: This answer is nearly identical to max's answer.